# Normal extension and Embeddings

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $K\subseteq Z\subseteq L\subseteq N$ be fields such that $N$ is normal over $K$. For each $K$ embedding $\sigma\in Emb_K(Z,N)$, is it always possible to extend $\sigma$ to an automorphism of $N$?

Can someone state the results used to answer this question and help me see this?
Thanks

Comment: What does $\;Emb_K(Z,N)\;$ means??

Comment: A homomorphism from $Z$ to $N$ which leaves $K$ pointwise fixed. One idea is let $\sigma$ be given and restrict it to $K$. Then this extends to an isomorphism of splitting fields, $N$ in this case. But why should this be an extension of the given $\sigma$ as well.?

Comment: @DonAntonio The set of field embeddings $Z\to N$ such that the given copy of $K$ inside $Z$ is sent to the given copy of $K$ inside $N$, pointwise. (This is standard terminology, although usually denoted with Hom's IIRC.)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the extension $\;N/K\;$ is algebraic or perhaps even finite? I mean, normality usually involves algebraicity, AFAIK.

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes $N/K$ is algebraic. What is AFAIK

Comment: AFAIK=As Far As I Know.

Comment: By the way, the field $L$ seems to be irrelevant: why did you introduce it?

Comment: Ahhh, Nice observation. I wanted to prove that $|Emb_K(L,N)|=|Emb_K(Z,N)|.|Emb_Z(L,N)|. In doing so, i needed the above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can always extend $\sigma$ to a $K$-automorphism of $N$:

First extend $\sigma$ to a $K$-morphism $s:N\to\bar K$ with values into an algebraic closure $\bar K$ of $K$ containing $N$: this is posible by a theorem of Steinitz.
The normality of $N/K$ guarantees that actually $s(N)\subset N$, so that actually $s$ is a $K$ endomorphism of $N$.
Finally recall that every $K$-endomorphism $s:N\to N$ of an **algebraic** extension $K\subset N$ of fields is surjective, and thus is an isomorphism of $K$-extensions.

Comment: Thank you, Does the following argument work: Consider the algebraic extensions $Z\subseteq N\subseteq \overline{N}=\overline{Z}$. Hence every morphism $Z\to \overline{N}$ has an extension $N\to \overline{N}$. Since $N$ is normal this gives an automorphism of $N$. I am not quite sure if this works, so wondering if you could comment on it. I like your proof, and i have learned something from it, so thank you very much.

Comment: Dear user114539, it works but trivially because actually $\bar K=\bar Z=\bar N$.